# How do I get Cloud9 and noVNC to work so that JOptionPane is visible?

Tags: java, cloud9-ide, vnc

I had this previous question and ended up talking to C9 support, which helped me make some progress. To reiterate, the issue was running a simple Java program with JOptionPane:

```
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class Test
{ 
  public static void main ( String args[] ) 
  { 
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog (null, "This is a sample program" ); 
  } 
}
```

Resulted in these errors:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.awt.HeadlessException:                                                                                                      
No X11 DISPLAY variable was set, but this program performed an operation which requires it.                                                                 
  at java.awt.GraphicsEnvironment.checkHeadless(GraphicsEnvironment.java:207)                                                                         
  at java.awt.Window.<init>(Window.java:535)                                                                                                          
  at java.awt.Frame.<init>(Frame.java:420)                                                                                                            
  at java.awt.Frame.<init>(Frame.java:385)                                                                                                            
  at javax.swing.SwingUtilities$SharedOwnerFrame.<init>(SwingUtilities.java:1756)                                                                     
  at javax.swing.SwingUtilities.getSharedOwnerFrame(SwingUtilities.java:1831)                                                                         
  at javax.swing.JOptionPane.getRootFrame(JOptionPane.java:1697)                                                                                      
  at javax.swing.JOptionPane.showOptionDialog(JOptionPane.java:863)                                                                                   
  at javax.swing.JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(JOptionPane.java:667)                                                                                  
  at javax.swing.JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(JOptionPane.java:638)                                                                                  
  at javax.swing.JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(JOptionPane.java:609)                                                                                  
  at Test.main(Test.java:8)
```

Obviously there is no GPU or monitor, so it needs to be emulated. I was given the following steps:

First, to set parameters:

```
sudo apt-get install xvfb x11-xkb-utils xfonts-100dpi xfonts-75dpi xfonts-scalable x11-apps
```

Second, to make display available and give it the number 99:

```
Xvfb :99 -ac -screen 0 1280x1024x16 &
```

Third, create a x11vnc password:

```
x11vnc -storepasswd s3cr3t3 ~/.vnc/passwd
```

Fourth, start the VNC server.

```
sudo x11vnc -rfbauth ~/.vnc/passwd -xkb -noxrecord -noxfixes -noxdamage -ncache 10 -rfbport 5900 -display :99 &
```

Fifth, this causes it to listen on port 5900, but only 8080 is available, so noVNC is needed:

```
git clone git://github.com/kanaka/noVNC
```

Sixth, run noVNC:

```
./noVNC/utils/launch.sh --vnc localhost:5900
```

I don't run into issues until I try to use my browser to connect to noVNC. There seems to be three was to do this:

This was given to me by C9 support:

```
https://<workspace>-<username>.c9.io/vnc.html
```

This is what noVNC generates to point browser to:

```
http://<username>-<workspace>-1260462:6080/vnc.html?host=<username>-<workspace>-1260462&port=6080
```

Then there is also this website where can specify host, port, passwords, etc.

```
http://kanaka.github.io/noVNC/noVNC/vnc.html
```

At any rate, I can never connect and I am not sure what I am doing wrong. I have verified all the steps up to starting noVNC have initialized correctly and are currently running. I have read pretty much all the documentation on it. Running this on Windows 7 with the latest Chrome.

Regards

Comment: I'm not sure if this will help out but you can get X11 working on Cloud9 using [Cloud9 VNC](https://github.com/fjakobs/cloud9-vnc).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't have this completely working but I might be a single small step closer than you. Your steps were really helpful to me. I can start X11 applications but not interact with them. I can only see the initial screen.

You need to modify the line where you start the noVNC server:

`./noVNC/utils/launch.sh --vnc localhost:5900 --listen 8080 &`

You can then access the noVNC web service on the following url from your normal browser:

`https://<workspace>-<user>.c9users.io/vnc.html`

When noVNC asks for connection details, you can connect with the pre-filled hostname `<workspace><-<user>.c9users.io` port `443` and password set in the earlier step, `s3cr3t3` in your example.

From the Cloud8 IDE workspace you can now open applications which draw to the VNC server and are visible through noVNC. For example:

`env DISPLAY=:99 xterm`

Reference: https://docs.c9.io/v1.0/docs/multiple-ports